# WPF MediaElement with source URL never HasTimeSpan?

Tags: wpf, url, mediaelement

I try to play a video from a URL source. When `MediaOpened` is fired, the test in

```
private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mediaView.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

always returns false and positioning within the media timespan is not possible.

Remark: If I use a file as source then `HasTimeSpan` is true and `MediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan` can be retrieved.

Is this always the case for URL based sources ?

Is there another way to get the duration of a media for URL based sources ?

I'm using .net 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the video format you use. I tested this code and it works fine.

**XAML:**

```
 <MediaElement
            x:Name="mediaView"
            MediaOpened="OnMediaOpened"
            Source="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.mp4" />
```

**Code:**

```
 private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mediaView.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It has TimeSpan and its duration is : " + Convert.ToString(mediaView.NaturalDuration) );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes it works with the URL you used. The URL I use for testing is "http://localhost:8080/SoccerApp/SpielVideoServlet?id=1832" This is a Tomcat 9 Webserver on my computer providing a self developed Java servlet. I'm testing the Http connection prior to playing the video, the 'HttpWebResponse.ContentType' is "video/mp4".
**Remark**: Recently I have also developed a JavaFX desktop application using its MediaView. In this environment accessing the URL above delivers a duration.

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile I can not reproduce the issue described in my question. The video streamed from my Tomcat via a servlet (see my comment to HYA's answer) now has a time span. I wonder if this is due to a "minor" update in the .Net framework.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand why my answer to my question was downvoted.
At the time of creation of the question the issue was reproducible and I enhanced my application to cope with the situation.
Some weeks later I discovered the issue has somehow gone.